# Get each character from each string by column

Tags: java, string, algorithm, loops, loop-invariant

I've been trying to get each character from every String by column but I only got the first characters of every string, I want to get every character by column from every string.

**For example:**

I have three strings from ArrayList of Strings:

1. chi
2. llo
3. ut

What I want to happen must be like this, after getting each character by column from strings:

1. clu
2. hlt
3. io

So long, my current source code only gets the first characters of first two string which is '**cl**', Here's my current source code:

```
List<String> New_Strings = new ArrayList<String>();
int Column_Place = 0;
for (String temp_str : Strings) {
    try{ //For StringIndexOutOfBoundsException (handle last String)
        if(Column_Place >= temp_str.length()){
            Current_Character = temp_str.charAt(Column_Place);
            New_Strings.add(Character.toString(Current_Character));
            break;
        }else if (Column_Place < temp_str.length()){
            Current_Character = temp_str.charAt(Column_Place);
            New_Strings.add(Character.toString(Current_Character));
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        continue;
    }
    Column_Place++;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to share how you have declared these variables as well. Also please follow the java naming conventions. Your code is nearly impossible to read.

Comment: I disagree with a posting that says the code is "nearly impossible to read"; it is true that starting variable names with a lower-case letter is a strong convention followed nearly everywhere. The biggest problem I see with the code is that we don't know how `New_Strings` is declared. It appears to be some kind of list of strings, but will get a new string for every letter in every source string, and that doesn't match the desired output. I *think* what you want is a list of strings, and to append each character from column N to string N, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding string representations of the individual characters to the result string. Instead, you should accumulate these characters in to a result string. E.g.:

```
int numStrings = strings.size();
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(numStrings);
for (int i = 0; i < numStrings; ++i) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : strings) {
        if (i < s.length) {
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    result.add(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: I changed the for loop condition to i <= numStrings to satisfy some inputs like: hxfcbvrqssbjavupuhby

Answer (score 0):

You iterate on the List with a enhanced/foreach loop. 
So you will iterate a single time on each 
String.  Whereas your result : only the first letters are hanlded.
You should use a `while` loop with as `while` condition `while(Column_Place < Strings.size())` with such an approach.
Or as alternative you could do things in two distinct steps and use Java 8 features.

Note that in Java, variables starts with lowercase.  Please follow the conventions to make your code more readable/understandable here and there.

In Java 8 you could do :

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("chi", "llo", "ut"));

int maxColumn = strings.stream()
                 .mapToInt(String::length)
                 .max()
                 .getAsInt(); // suppose that you have at least one element in the List


List<String> values =
        // stream from 0 the max number of column
        IntStream.range(0, maxColumn) 
                 // for each column index : create the string by joining their 
                 // String value or "" if index out of bound
                 .mapToObj(i -> strings.stream() 
                                       .map(s -> i < s.length() ? String.valueOf(
                                               s.charAt(i)) : "")
                                       .collect(Collectors.joining()))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call *groupByColumn(Arrays.asList("chi", "llo", "ut")*:

```
public static List<String> groupByColumn(List<String> words) {
    if (words == null || words.isEmpty()) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    return IntStream.range(0, longestWordLength(words))
            .mapToObj(ind -> extractColumn(words, ind))
            .collect(toList());

}

public static String extractColumn(List<String> words, int columnInd) {
    return words.stream()
            .filter(word -> word.length() > columnInd)
            .map(word -> String.valueOf(word.charAt(columnInd)))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
}

public static int longestWordLength(List<String> words) {
    String longestWord = Collections.max(words, Comparator.comparing(String::length));
    return longestWord.length();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just think the list as two dimensional array. split each item from the list, get the j-th character from each item, if and only if the item's length is greater than the index j.

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("chi");
    list.add("llo");
    list.add("ut");


    int size = list.size();
    int i=0, j=0,k=0;
    while(size-- > 0){
        for(i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            String temp = list.get(i);
            if(j < temp.length()){
                System.out.print(temp.charAt(j));
            }
        }
        j++;
        System.out.println();
    }
```